# Breeze entityManager importEntities duplicating updated child entities

Tags: breeze

I am trying to use the ["sandbox editor"](http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/multiple-entitymanagers.html) approach with [exportEntities and importEntities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/export-import.html) as detailed in the [Cool Breezes](http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/import-save-results.html) section (and in many SO posts).

I have a main/parent entity which has one or more child entities. I have an HTML view (using [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) but that doesn't matter) that displays the 4 properties from the parent entity and then 3 or 4 properties from each of the child entities. In this example the parent has just one child entity.

The view uses a new entityManager and the parent/child entities have been imported from the 'master' entityManager in the usual export/import way. So far so good.

I edit one of the properties on the child entity and save it. I pass the saveResult to a copy of the `updateMasterWithSaveResult`. Everything works fine up to the line `masterEm.importEntities(exported);`

- imports[] contains just one updated child entity - correct.
- deletes[] is empty - correct.
- exported contains the updated child entity info - correct.
- masterEm contains the original parent and the original (non-updated) child - correct.

**The problem**

After it has called `masterEm.importEntities(exported)`, masterEm now contains the original parent BUT the child property array now has **2 elements** in it and both of them are the same, updated, child element. They are identical - same key, same everything.

**Analysis**

After much tracing I've narrowed this down to `_linkRelatedEntities` in [a50_entityManager.js](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/a50_entityManager.js#L1562). At the bottom of this function it [handles the foreign keys](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/a50_entityManager.js#L1656) of the child and calls `parent.getProperty(invNp.name).push(entity)` or `parent.getProperty(invNp.name)._push(entity)` but
doesn't appear to check if the child is already connected. So in this case the child entity is 
already in the array but gets added a second time.

**Question**: Is this the expected outcome? And, if so, am I missing something or is there a 'proper' way around it so that I end up with only one child element?

My temporary solution is to run a de-duplication on the child array after running `importEntities` but that seems hacky to say the least.

Comment: I've seen this in my project as well. I remember at the time that it occurred randomly to non-specific entities and I could never determine why or what I did to solve it. I'll dig into my code and see if I put a hedge somewhere

Comment: @jonathan, thanks, at least I'm not the only one. I'd appreciate any insight. The entities in question will only ever have 5 or 6 child entities max so the de-dupe isn't horrendous - just seems so wrong.

Comment: I posted this related question several months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138139/icollection-navigation-property-contains-detached-entities I think when I added `updateMasterWithSaveResult` from the link you posted it fixed my issue.  Are some of your duplicate entities detached?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. In this case there are no detached entities. In fact, the reason I started using the `updateMasterWithSaveResult` function in the first place was to be able to cope with detached in due course. Guess I'll live with it for the time being - but I'll check a bit deeper into the entityState too....